# Sending a URL/filePath in Resteasy request

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, resteasy

I want to send path of a file alongwith some Strings.
After spending some time I was unable to find anything that can help. Could anyone suggest any link on how to do this on server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of the following methods to submit a file path and some strings to the server:

1. Submit a Form with the file path and strings.
2. Encode the file path and send it as a query parameter in the URL along with the strings.
3. Create a message body containing the file path and other strings you want to send and submit it via a `POST` call.
4. Send the file path and strings in custom http headers.

Take a look at the Resteasy documentation here: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.4.Final/userguide/html_single/

Pay special attention to the sections that talk about using the `@Form`, `@FormParam`, `@QueryParam`, and `@POST` annotations.